# how to watch struct's change process use gdb

Tags: gdb

I'am now dealing with a new project, threre exist several struct for varaible transfering in parallel programming, can anybody give some hint on how to use gdb to watch struct chage process step by step, thanks first:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try GDB [`watch`](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html#Set-Watchpoints) command. However, as stated by this link :

> Warning: In multi-thread programs,
>   watchpoints have only limited
>   usefulness. With the current
>   watchpoint implementation, GDB can
>   only watch the value of an expression
>   in a single thread.

If that's a deal breaker for you, I guess you will have to instrument your code to manually track changes.